# Google Apps error - Can't communicate with google servers

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, google-apps

I'm having trouble with everything that pertains to google. I've read what you people have recommended and I'm still having troubles with Google Play and the Google Apps. I removed all my accounts and restarted phone. When I click on the Play store, its giving me an error saying **Can't communicate with google servers, please try again later.**
 I've tried everything I could think of. I don't know what to do.

Comment: If clearing the cache does not work then you might need to check your APN. Is it a new phone? Do you have any type of data access at all on the device?

Comment: Please link what relevant info you've read on this site and precisely mention what you've followed so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can stop the Play Store faltering just by emptying the app's cache. The cache is a storage area that temporarily holds data so it can be quickly retrieved without needing to be reloaded. To empty the cache:

Go to Settings > Apps. Tap All > Google Play Store then finally tap the Clear cache button.

Clear out your Play Store data 
Deleting your data from the Play Store works along the same lines as our first tip, but is more drastic. It sets the app back to square one and gets rid of your saved information, hopefully including whatever glitchy data was causing the problem.

As with the previous tip, go to Settings > Apps > Google Play Store, but this time tap Clear data